# Remove content from HTML with f:format.html

Tags: typo3, typoscript, fluid, typo3-8.x

I want my homepage to have a list of articles, with the first bit of text from each as a preview. Something like:

```
<div class="article">
    <h2>Article Title</h2>
    <div class="article-text">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Curabitur tortor quam, vulputate at pharetra et, molestie vel nisi. Donec quis tellus pretium, sollicitudin neque et, tristique nunc. Proin id nunc augue. Quisque iaculis iaculis dui, et dictum tortor.</p>
        <p>Morbi ligula felis, rhoncus at felis a, egestas scelerisque metus. In sit amet urna nec sem tristique fringilla vel nec sem. Nullam at ante</p>
    </div>
    <p class="read-more"><a href="/article-title/">Read More…</a></p>
</div>
```

So, in my fluid template, I had:

```
<div class="article-text">
    <f:format.crop maxCharacters="480" respectHtml="true">
        <v:content.render column="0" pageUid="{article.uid}" />
    </f:format.crop>
</div>
```

And as long as the article starts with text, this works fine. But then I had an article which started with some images with captions, like:

```
<div class="img-grid">
    <figure>
        <img src="/fileadmin/image1.jpg">
        <figcaption>Here's a picture of a thing</figcaption>
    </figure>
    <figure>
        <img src="/fileadmin/image2.jpg">
        <figcaption>Here's a picture of another thing</figcaption>
    </figure>
</div>
<p>Lorem ipsum, etc., etc...</p>
```

What I want is to somehow strip out that `<div class="img-grid">`, to instead show starting with the first bit of regular text from the article. I think the correct way to do this would be with `<f:format.html>`, but for some reason it isn't working for me. In my fluid template, I have:

```
<f:format.crop maxCharacters="480" respectHtml="true">
    <f:format.html parseFuncTSPath="lib.parseFunc_List">
        <v:content.render column="0" pageUid="{article.uid}" />
    </f:format.html>
</f:format.crop>
```

And in my TypoScript setup.txt I have:

```
lib.parseFunc_List {
    externalBlocks {
        figure.stdWrap.HTMLparser = 1
        figure.stdWrap.HTMLparser {
            tags.figure = 0
            tags.figcaption = 0
            tags.img = 0
            removeTags = "figure, figcaption, img"
        }
    }
}
```

But it doesn't strip anything out.

How can I parse my HTML, and remove the content I don't want?

Answer (score 0):

If you just remove tags you still have the content, here the image captions.

If you only want the text part you might change the rendering of the CEs so you could more easily identify the text part. you might use a html comment before and after the text part and extract that substring before you use the crop VH.

You also have the option to render your content individually ignoring any / most types. this can be done in typoscript (`CONTENT` with individual `renderObj`) or in a PHP VH.